# Как запустить gradle task в отдельном .gradle файле

Tags: java, android, gradle

Как запустить gradle task в отдельном .gradle файле до assembleDebug

Т.е. у меня в **build.gradle** (Project: gradle)

```
buildscript {
    //something
}

allprojects{
    //something
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleDebug') {
        task.dependsOn mytask
    }
}
```

И есть файл **mytask.gradle** в котором

```
task mytask << {
    println "mytask run!"
}
```

Не выполняется. 
Есть вот такая ошибка: `Could not get unknown property 'mytask' for root project 'gradle' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

**Как запустить gradle task в отдельном .gradle файле до выполнения assembleDebug?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить

> apply from: 'gradle/mytask.gradle'

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593836/run-a-file-mytask-gradle-before-executing-assembledebug